# Can't run Droid4X under wine

Tags: wine

I get the error:

> wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\home\amorris\programs\droid4x-0-9-0.exe.

when I try to open a `.exe` file with `wine droid4x-0-9-0.exe`. How do I fix this?

Comment: I very much doubt an Android emulator would run in Wine.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, do not run Wine as root.

Bad EXE error appears to be generated because you are trying to run a 32 bit app with pure 64 bit Wine. That will not work.

Try the [WineHQ Debian package](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian) instead or the [Arch Linux package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/multilib/x86_64/wine/).

Comment: I am not running wine as root (I am not super user); I have installed it only for my account. I am running Arch Linux so I doubt the Debian package will work :P

Comment: No problem, there's wine 2.9-1 (x86_64) for Arch.

Answer (score 0):

Bad EXE format could be related to corrupted or not supported executable file.

First of all, verify that you've downloaded the whole file correctly and the EXE file is valid by using `sigcheck` utility (part of [*Sysinternals Suite*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)).

I've tested [`droid4x-0-9-0.exe` file](https://droid4x.en.softonic.com/download) under wine-2.0.3 on macOS and it runs, but it crashes, however it doesn't report the EXE as invalid.

For the crash issue, I've reported the bug at [#43994 at WineHQ Bug Tracking Database](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43994).